# Unknown Property Error, VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce

I want to show the results of a Json response on a Visualforce page. At this moment im able to deserialize and show the results, but when I try to show the result of the Class in the visual force it shows the following error:

[image]

For testing i want to show in the VF page "Razon Social" of the class Empresa.

This is the class:

```
public class EquifaxEmpresa {

public List<Empresa> Empresa;

public class Empresa{
    public String RazonSocial; 
    public String NombreComercial;  
    public String TipoContribuyente; 
    public String EstadoContribuyente;
    public String CondicionContribuyente; 
    public String Dependencia; 
    public String CodigoCIIU; 
    public String DescripcionCIIU; 
    public String InicioActividades; 
    public String ActividadComercioExterior; 
    public String NumeroTrabajadores; 
    public String Direccion;
}
public static EquifaxEmpresa parse(String json){
    return (EquifaxEmpresa) System.JSON.deserialize(json, EquifaxEmpresa.class);
}}
```

This is the controller class:

```
global class equifaxController {
public String idConsulta {get;set;}
public EquifaxEmpresa theEmpresa {get;set;}
public String mensaje {get;set;}

public void consultaPersona(){

    string msj = '{'+
                 '"NroDocumento":"'+idConsulta+'",'+
                 '"Consulta":"Empresa"'+
                 '}';

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('endpoint here');
    req.setBody(msj);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setTimeout(12000);

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

    //EquifaxEmpresa empresita = (EquifaxEmpresa)JSON.deserialize(msj, EquifaxEmpresa.class);

    res = Http.send(req);
    String temp = res.toString();

    if(temp.contains('Error')){
        system.debug('Error: '+res.getStatusCode());
    }else{
        String body = res.getBody();
        theEmpresa = EquifaxEmpresa.parse(body);
        system.debug(theEmpresa.Empresa[0].RazonSocial);
        mensaje = body;
    }
}
}
```

The visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="equifaxController">


       <apex:pageBlock title="Datos de Empresa">
           <apex:form >
            <apex:inputText value="{!idConsulta }"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Consultar" action="{!consultaPersona}" reRender="dynamic"/>
           </apex:form>
       </apex:pageBlock>


    <apex:outputPanel id="dynamic">
        {!theEmpresa.Empresa[0].RazonSocial}
    </apex:outputPanel>   

</apex:page>
```

The other thing that I cannot understand, its why system.debug shows me *{!theEmpresa.Empresa[0].RazonSocial}* and VF not:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think declaring it  like this `public List<Empresa> Empresa {get;set}` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce requires a "getter" and "setter" to reference a variable in the controller or extension. Without a getter or setter, even public or global variables cannot be referenced in Visualforce expressions.

So declare the list like this:

```
public List<Empresa> Empresa {get;set}
public String RazonSocial {get;set}
```

Comment: In the problems section appears: Invalid Type: Empresa

Comment: Refer the updated answer.

Comment: these declarations go in the Controller or the empresa class? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you've already declared it, just append it with getter and setters

Comment: Thanks!! It worked.